# Candidate is not '@objc' but protocol requires it

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have been following this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/75289/swift-tutorial-part-3-tuples-protocols-delegates-table-views) to learn swift & iOS app development. In the Protocol section, the tutorial defined the following protocol:

```
@objc protocol Speaker {
  func Speak()
  optional func TellJoke()
}
```

It says **If you want to have a protocol with optional methods, you must prefix the protocol with the @objc tag (even if your class is not interoperating with objective-C)**.

Then, it shows the sample to implement the protocol:

```
class Vicki: Speaker {
  func Speak() {
    println("Hello, I am Vicki!")
  }
  func TellJoke() {
    println("Q: What did Sushi A say to Sushi B?")
  }
}
```

I tried the above code in my xcode playground, but I got the compiler error **"Type Vicki doesn't conform to protocol Speaker"**.

Xcode also pops up an **fix-it** text which says **"Candidate is not '@objc' but protocol requires it"**.

I get completely confused now, the tutorial doesn't mention this error at all. Could someone please explain to me all this to make me clear? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I can tell, marking your protocol as @objc means that any classes implementing it also have to be exposed to Objective-C. This can be done either by making Vicki a subclass of NSObject:

```
class Vicki: NSObject, Speaker {
```

Or by marking each implemented method as @objc:

```
class Vicki: Speaker {
    @objc func Speak() {
        print("Hello, I am Vicki!")
    }
    @objc func TellJoke() {
        print("Q: What did Sushi A say to Sushi B?")
    }
}
```

Update: From Apple's [Swift Language Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

> Optional protocol requirements can only be specified if your protocol is marked with the @objc attribute.
>
> ...
>
> Note also that @objc protocols can be adopted only by classes, and not
>   by structures or enumerations. If you mark your protocol as @objc in
>   order to specify optional requirements, you will only be able to apply
>   that protocol to class types.

Comment: Does the tutorial teach right that "If you want to have a protocol with optional methods, you must prefix the protocol with the @objc tag " ?

Comment: Yes it does, see my update with a link to official Apple documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a type to conform to a protocol marked `@objc`, that type must also marked with `@objc` or the methods being used to satisfy the protocol must be.

Using `@objc` on a declaration tells the compiler to expose it to the Objective-C runtime.  In order for that to be possible, the type that was declared `@objc` must be able to be represented in Objective-C.

For classes this means they must inherit from NSObject.  For methods, this means they become backed by dynamic Objective-C message passing.

Comment: Does the tutorial teach right that "If you want to have a protocol with optional methods, you must prefix the protocol with the @objc tag " ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we only need to prefix protocol method with `@objc` in private class.

```
private class A: NSObject, SomeObjcProtocol {
  @objc func someProtocolMethod() {}
}
```

Warning is not likely to rise for non-private class.

```
class A: NSObject, SomeObjcProtocol {
  func someProtocolMethod() {}
}
```

Both are fine.

Comment: Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Add an extension to the protocol returning empty functions and default values.  Any class that conforms to the protocol and wishes to override any func or var may *optionally* do so.

```
    public protocol Speaker {
      func Speak()
      func TellJoke()
    }

    extension Speaker {
      func Speak() {}
      func TellJoke() { print("What did the Teabag say to the Octopus?"}
    }
```

The bonuses are you don't inherit all of the obj-c baggage.