# Not able to implement RideRequestButtonDelegate in swift 2.2

Tags: uber-api

I am trying to assign a delegate to uber ios widget RideRequestButton.

```
class UberRideRequestButtonDelegate:RideRequestButtonDelegate{
    func rideRequestViewController(rideRequestViewController: RideRequestViewController, didReceiveError error: NSError) {
       let errorType = RideRequestViewErrorType(rawValue: error.code) ?? .Unknown
       print("errorType\(errorType)")
    }
   func rideRequestButton(button: RideRequestButton, didReceiveError error: RidesError){

   }
}
```

I am getting the error - ***"Type UberRideRequestButtonDelegate does not confirm to protocol RideRequestButtonDelegate"***

Answer (score 0):

The error message usually includes additional information about which methods are missing. Can you provide the full error? You are likely missing those methods.

Comment: I get this additonal error: "Fix-It  Candidate is not '@objc', but protocol requires it.". I click to fix it and it add @objc to the func rideRequestButton

Comment: I am still facing this issue and have not been able to resolve it. Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Here is the relevant stackoverflow article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941771/candidate-is-not-objc-but-protocol-requires-it